# Eclipse Juno - GCC compiler pthread

Tags: c, eclipse, pthreads

So I'm currently in a practical session at my university and not a single person can figure out how to add the pthread library in Eclipse. This is my first time with Eclipse though.

I'm using Fedora, and when I go to Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings, all I get is a drop-down list for configurations and nothing else - no tabs for tools to add it.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

[image: Damn]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have in Project -> Settings -> C/C++ Build the option "Generate Makefile automatically" selected! Otherwise Eclipse assumes you are providing your own makefile and doesn't show the "Tool setting" tab.

Then you need to go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build do [**this**](http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/02/15/adding-pthread-to-eclipse-for-using-posix-threads/).

[image]

Comment: I might just walk out of here. I go there and there's no Library or Library Paths tab.

Comment: Are you doing exactly this? http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/02/15/adding-pthread-to-eclipse-for-using-posix-threads/

Comment: @Stickerbox Make sure you have in Project -> Settings -> C/C++ Build the option "Generate Makefile automatically" selected! Otherwise Eclipse assumes you are providing your own makefile and doesn't show the "Tool setting" tab

Comment: Ok so when I go there it's not available for me to click. However when I create a new project with the project type MakeFile->Empty Project, I can tick it and add the library, but have no idea where to put my code.

Comment: @Stickerbox `File -> New -> Source file` to add a source code file. Similar for header files. Anyway, this is now not related to the question.