# Compiling openmp with GNU gcc fails in Windows

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I have Windows 8 64bit operating system.

I wanted to experiment with following C code for OpenMP functionality:

`hello.c` program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

While I tried to run the program from command prompt using:
`gcc -fopenmp hello.c`

I got the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have `C:\MinGW` in my path with `gcc 4.8.1`.

What is it I am missing?

Comment: MinGw didn't support the libpthread library on Windows - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library As recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21827981/196561 you may try to install pthreads-win32 library from https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  osgx,

As a newbie I couldn't make out what these `pthreads` meant.
But after all I found solution to my problem.
I installed `gcc 4.8.2 64 bit` on my machine from http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran.
It changed the environment variable (in path) itself. After finishing installation,
I restarted my computer
and when I typed:

```
gcc -fopenmp hello.c
```

for the above code in command line, the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

The other trick is to use [docker container with gcc](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/).

Steps:

1. Install docker
2. In the docker terminal: `docker pull gcc`
3. Then run a terminal and mount a host folder where your C scripts are inside the gcc container by typing: `docker run -it -v /hostfolder:/folderincontainer gcc /bin/bash`
4. Then execute the script in the terminal.

Its simple. No need to worry about the specifics of OS.