# Eclipse MinGW C++ cannot find -lpthread

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I am currently trying to install Eclipse for making C++ programs.

I've run into an issue when compiling the premade default hello world program.

The console shows this error:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread

I am not using the library in my program at all.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running the program directly from the command line?

Comment: And are you using **any** libraries at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just run and open MinGW Installation Manager, which should be pre-installed with MinGW, select "All Packages" on the left panel, and on the right panel, search for "**mingw32-pthreads-w32**" packages and install them.

Restart Eclipse, rebuild the project and run it. It should now work.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer helped me a lot.

Comment: How can I thank you, i have been struggling here for days

Comment: I tried the same but I am not using eclipse. I am trying to compile the code using command line and still it fails with the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem even with those packages installed.  I had to go to mingw\lib and copy the file  libpthreadGC-3.a  and rename it to libpthread.a  and the file libpthreadGC-3.dll.a rename it to libpthread.dll.a

After that it works!

Answer (score 0):

After installing MinGw mingw-gcc-g++, reopen Eclipse, then clear errors. Once all the errors are cleared, try rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have cygwin installed ... see the [question on mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library). I ended up with adding `'C:/cygwin/lib'` to the settings for the "Library search path (-L)" at `properties >> c/c++ build >> settings >> MinGW C Linker >> Libraries`.