# Fixing MinGW Installation on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

While helping my friend spin up MinGW and a C++ environment on his Windows 8 computer, I ran the get-mingw script and waited as it ran through all the mirrors for required downloads. However, three downloads completely failed:

- `libltdl` - installer script hung and then moved on after pressing "OK"
- `automake-1.11` - installer script tried finding 1.10, then 1.9, then 1.8, then 1.7 (all of which failed) until finally settling on 1.6
- `mktemp` - script hung and moved on after pressing "OK"

In all three cases, the script gave me a nice error log upon completion, showing that a majority of packages had been downloaded and installed except for these three, which showed up as errors. However during the installation process I had simply gone to the MinGW sourceforge page and manually found and downloaded each `.bin.tar.lzma` file that was missing.

Now that I have them, is there a good accepted way to unpack and plug them into my friend's existing MinGW install? In case it's tough, I'm comfortable with unix and dos command line so I'll be able to move executables into the MinGW/bin folder if that's what's needed, I just want to check for the best way to 'fix' the install.

As a side note - even though the error log says these are required packages, adding MinGW/bin/ to the PATH still allows for use of `gcc` and `g++`, although not `make` (possibly because of `automake` failure?). Is this standard behavior?

Comment: I think the main MinGW g++ distribution now is MinGW-64 (or thereabouts, taking names from hazy memory). STL's distro at nuwen.net is based on that. It offers very easy installation at the cost of no support for character encodings. The TDM distro has support for character encodings and in the old days two exception models, I don't know how it's now. But just check things. Preferably don't use silly scripts. Just use an installer, or copy the files to their proper places (it helps to have a working installation from some distro, e.g. Nuwen). Archives, e.g. zip files, are nice.

Comment: Thanks for the Nuwen suggestion! It looks a lot easier than the script my friend had downloaded ... but unfortunately he was too invested in MinGW at that point because the installer was running. I'll definitely use that next time someone I know needs c++ :P

Comment: You could install [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org) instead, which has a [self-installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/?source=recommended) that works without requiring any mucking around

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the package issue can be fixed by using the MinGW installer - keep the packages selected and go to "apply changes" and the script will probably try to redownload the missing packages. I think the original problem was probably just a shoddy wifi connection during repository connection.

However, I then ran into a problem where I tried to run `gcc` and it gave me a `missing -lpthread` error ... but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185248/eclipse-mingw-c-cannot-find-lpthread) was able to help me fix that, and `gcc` and `g++` are working fine now (haven't opened and tested Eclipse yet though). Just in case of link decay, the issue I cited arises from the MinGW installer script not downloading the lpthread library upon installation. To fix *that* issue, quoted from link:

> Just run and open MinGW Installation Manager, which should be pre-installed with MinGW, select "All Packages" on the left panel, and on the right panel, search for "mingw32-pthreads-w32" packages and install them.

I think the Installation Manager has `libpthread` and `pthread` available for install, and `pthread` libs were the ones that seemed to solve it for me.