# How can i compile c++ with openmp? (using g++ in windows 10)

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, openmp

i'm new in c++ programming. Also new in openMP.
I have this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf("This is thread %d out of %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to compile it using

```
g++ -fopenmp file_name.cpp
```

in the cmd, i get this error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot 
find -lpthread collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use windows 10, and the gcc version is 6.3.0.
How can i fix this?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002304/how-to-compile-openmp-using-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MinGW32, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185248/eclipse-mingw-c-cannot-find-lpthread) would help.

Or you can use TDM-GCC. You can download full TDM-GCC installers and be sure to enable openmp support when you install. Packages is also OK like *gcc-5.1.0-tdm64-1-core.zip* with *gcc-5.1.0-tdm64-1-openmp.zip* extracted to the same folder.