# Cannot build C project by using Eclipse in Linux

Tags: c, sockets, compiler-errors, pthreads, chat

I have a small project in C programing, Eclipse Linux. But when I build it I always get an error **"undefined reference to `pthread_create'"** at line

```
re = pthread_create(&interrupt, NULL, clientHandler, NULL);
```

I have no idea about I get this issue. I also searched and tried applying a solution discussed at [Eclipse Juno - GCC compiler pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770147/eclipse-juno-gcc-compiler-pthread) but it still appears. So, is there another way that I can apply to solve it?

Here is the code of mine https://ide.c9.io/nkphuc700/cworkspace, the issue fires at line 51.

Error message on Console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Eclipse to build code. AFAIK, it will just run some builder commands (perhaps using `make`) which in turn runs the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

You should compile with `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pthread -g` and link with 
 `gcc -pthread` *...your object files....* `-o yourprogram` *...your libraries...* `-lpthread`

Comment: it still appears...I tried compiling the C files by using Linux terminal and I still get the same message.

Comment: Then edit your question to give exactly the compilation commands. Notice that order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot.

Comment: I solved the issue by compiling my C files in terminal Linux. I used *-pthread* flag in the command *gcc main.c -o main.out -pthread*. Thanks for your help. Your soluton did suggest me about the flag. I will accept your answer